# Searching through a Hashset for words within a file

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner, hashset

I've got a `Hashset` with my dictionary of words in it.

What I'm trying to do is to individually scan words from the file `checkMe` to see whether they exist in my `HashSet`.

When a word doesn't exist, I need to trigger a number of actions (which I won't get into).

For now, I'd like some advice as to how I take words from my scanned file and check them against my `HashSet`.

Something like:

```
if (dicSet does not contain a word in checkMe) {
    da da da 
}
```

Also, I want to be able to loop through `checkMe` to make sure each word is checked through `dicSet` until I reach an error.

My code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class spelling{
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

//read the dictionary file
Scanner dicIN = new Scanner(new File("dictionary.txt"));
//read the spell check file
Scanner spellCheckFile = new Scanner(new File("checkMe.txt"));

//create Hashset
Set <String> dicSet = new HashSet<String>();
//Scan from spell check file
Scanner checkMe = new Scanner(spellCheckFile);


//Loop through dictionary and store them into set. set all chars to lower case just in case because java is case sensitive
    while(dicIN.hasNext())
    {
        String dicWord = dicIN.next();
        dicSet.add(dicWord.toLowerCase());
    }   
//make comparisons for words in spell check file with dictionary
    if(dicSet){

    }


    // System.out.println(dicSet);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(checkMe.hasNext())
{
    String checkWord = checkMe.next();
    if (!dicSet.contains(checkWord.toLowerCase())) {
        // found a word that is not in the dictionary
    }
}
```

That's the basic idea at least. For real use, you'd have to add a ton of error-checking and exceptional states handling (what if your input contains numbers? What about `.`, `-` etc?)